# How would you pass an user though all the app?

Tags: android, singleton

I'm creating an app where the user has to log-in in order to use it. I often need data about the logged user, in multiple activities. I assume it's not a good idea to always pass the user by Intent, and I just learned that singletons are supposed to be really bad. So what is the "nice" way to do that?

What is the nice way to have an object that I can access from anywhere and only have to store once, when the user opens the app?

Comment: Multiple activities? Use fragments instead.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data  you can use shared preferences or implement a database in your app and work with it. assuming you have a sever side i'd go with getting the data once the user is logged in and save it in sqlite ( database optiom mentioned earlier )

Comment: Yes I should have said activites/fragments. I do use fragments, but I need to access information about the connected user in several of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition**

```
public class UserData {
public static UserData userDataInstance = new UserData();

public UserData() {
}

private String username = null;
private String firstName = null;
private String lastName = null;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

**Usage**

```
UserData.userDataInstance.setUsername('username');//To set username  
username = UserData.userDataInstance.getUsername();// To get username
```

Since, Singleton is not consistent data. I suggest you to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

**Usage**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
sp.edit.putString("username",username).commit();//TO save in SharedPreferences 
username = sp.getString("username",null);//To get string
```